# How to write spring boot unit test for a method which calls another @Async method inside it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, integration-testing

I need to write integration test for "processEvent" method which calls a @Async method inside it. I tried writing a test for this method, but the issue was it did not save the Student object to the DB. However removing @Async annotation allows me to save the object. I want to know how should I write Test cases for this method, eliminating the @Async issue. I want to save the student object while testing. I have attached my code and below.

Here is the ClassA and it has the method I want to test.

```
@Service
public class ClassA {

private final ConfigurationProcessor<Student> configurationProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public ClassA(ConfigurationProcessor<Student> configurationProcessor) {
        this.configurationProcessor = configurationProcessor;
    }

    public void processEvent(Configuration configuration) {
        configurationProcessor.process(configuration);
    }
}
```

This is the interface ConfigurationProcessor class

```
public interface ConfigurationProcessor<T> {
    void process(Configuration configuration);
}
```

And this is its Impl class

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationProcessoeStudents10Impl implements ConfigurationProcessor<Student> {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigurationProcessoeStudents10Impl(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
        }
    
    @Override
    @Async
    public void process(Configuration configuration) {
        studentRepository.save(Student.builder().Name(configuration.name).Age(configuration.age));
    }
}
```

This is the Test I have written so far.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class AudienceC10IT {

  @Autowired
  ClassA classA;
  
  @Test
  @Tag("VerifyProcess")
  @DisplayName("Verify kafka event consumer from configuration manager")
  void verifyProcess(){
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration("lal",12);
    classA.processEvent(configuration);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are not testing the async function you could mock it (and write separate tests for the async method elsewhere)

Comment: Is there any way to write this test without mocking ? I need to test that function as well :(

Comment: or else, do you know any way to test the @Async method directly ?

Comment: Not 100% sure this would work with async, but I would try with awaitility. await().atMost(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted{ >> assert that its saved << }. Perhaps with a Spy on the repository to verify save was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have have set up a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean you can Autowire it in your test.
Then, after you call your async method, you can await the termination.
Then you can check for the expected behaviour / result.

Something like this:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor;

@Test
void test() {
    callAsyncMethod();

    boolean terminated = asyncTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    assertAsyncBehaviour();


}
```